# Parameterizing a pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to parameterize a pandas group by instead of passing in the hardcoded list?

```
group_by_cols = "id","week_number"
aggregate_cols = "col1","col2","col3"
df = pd.read_csv(input_file_name)
df_total = df.groupby([group_by_cols])[aggregate_cols].sum()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want pass lists remove `[]` from `[group_by_cols]` for nested lists:

```
#for list added []
group_by_cols = ["id","week_number"]
aggregate_cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]

print (type(group_by_cols))
<class 'list'>

df = pd.read_csv(input_file_name)
df_total = df.groupby(group_by_cols)[aggregate_cols].sum()
```

Or if inputs are tuples convert them to lists like:

```
group_by_cols = "id","week_number"
aggregate_cols = "col1","col2","col3"
```

working same like passing tuples:

```
group_by_cols = ("id","week_number")
aggregate_cols = ("col1","col2","col3")

print (type(group_by_cols))
<class 'tuple'>

df = pd.read_csv(input_file_name)
df_total = df.groupby(list(group_by_cols))[list(aggregate_cols)].sum()
```

Sample data test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':list('aaaabb'),
         'week_number':[4,5,4,5,5,5],
         'col1':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'col2':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'col3':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'col4':[4,3,3,0,3,9]
})


group_by_cols = ["id","week_number"]
aggregate_cols = ["col1","col2","col3"]

df_total = df.groupby(group_by_cols)[aggregate_cols].sum()
print (df_total)
                col1  col2  col3
id week_number                  
a  4              16     6    11
   5              12    10    12
b  5               5     1     6
```

---

```
group_by_cols = "id","week_number"
aggregate_cols = "col1","col2","col3"

df_total = df.groupby(list(group_by_cols))[list(aggregate_cols)].sum()
print (df_total)
                col1  col2  col3
id week_number                  
a  4              16     6    11
   5              12    10    12
b  5               5     1     6
```

Comment: If I use the first option I get a warning "FutureWarning: Interpreting tuple 'by' as a list of keys, rather than a single key. Use 'by=[...]' instead of 'by=(...)'. In the future, a tuple will always mean a single key." Is the tuple the recommended way of doing it?

Comment: @Ram - hmmm, now  I am a bit confused, what is `print (type(group_by_cols))` ? It is list like in my first solution or tuple like in second one?